# Як описати фразу одним словом?

Tags: одним-словом

Яким іменником можна замінити вираз "щось не так"?
Наприклад у реченні "Він відчув,що щось не так"  Мій друг твердить, що його можна замінити словом "неладність", проте я не впевнена у його знаннях з української мови,як і в своїх.

Comment: Будь ласка, переформулюйте питання, бо поки що дуже складно зрозуміти, що саме ви запитуєте.

Comment: Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour](https://goo.gl/XbjRge), [How to Ask](https://goo.gl/KuCfff) а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](https://goo.gl/wnuKFr). Щоб виправити запитання, натисніть на edit.

Comment: @P.Vowk, перепрошую, якщо я пишу якусь маячню, але я не розумію, що незрозуміло. Автор(ка) хоче синонімів до фрази «щось не так». Нпавть сама пропонує почутий від друга варіант «неладність», але невпевнена в ньому. (Чи Ви маєте на увазі, щоб вона навела приклади ситуацій, які, на її думку, підпадають під вислів «щось не так»?)

Answer (score 6):

> [НЕГАРАЗД](http://sum.in.ua/s/negharazd), присл.
>
> 1. Погано, не дуже добре, **не так, як треба**. *Мірошник той Хомою звався, І був він чоловік такий, Що негаразд за діло брався* (Леонід Глібов, Вибр., 1951, 13); *Приголомшена несподіваним нагадуванням, не стала [мати] й сперечатися, хоча в душі була певна, що негаразд вони оце роблять, розлучаючи її з сином* (Олесь Гончар, II, 1959, 134);